# different Native vlans on the ends of trunk link

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan

http://www.techexams.net/forums/ccnp/53867-different-native-vlans-ends-trunk-link.html
so i read this, but i still can not get traffic between two ends of a trunk link, each with a different native VLAN

Answer (score 0):

Why do your links have different native vlans?

Are you having only the native vlan traffic fail to traverse the link?

It'd really be helpful if you could provide some real detail about why this is set up this way, the current configuration of the ports, and what you've tried.

However, I'm just going to jump to an answer: just tag your native vlans instead of trying to deal with untagged traffic.

```
switchport trunk native vlan tag
```

Comment: my traffic that im concerned about is tagged and is still not getting through,
Sw1# 
interface port-channel4
switch port allowed vlan 10,20,30
switch port native vlan 10
switch port mode trunk

interface1
switchport port-channel1
switch port trunk
switch port native vlan 10
switchport nonegotiate.

on Switch 2
i have same config but using native vlan 20,
i cant seem to get traffic on valn 30 from the other end of the trunk link

Comment: Well, if tagged traffic is not working then it's extremely unlikely that native vlan tagging (or lack of) is your problem.  Port channel configuration seems a likely suspect.. can you edit your question to include the full port channel and interface configurations from both sides of the link?

Comment: it worked, there was a misconfig